# H2 failing to insert data

Tags: h2

I am testing this DB and I am trying to insert data on a table with attributes: ID, password and username. I get this error:

```
bad SQL grammar
...
Syntax error in SQL statement "insert into users(id,username,password) values(2,'TEST[*]','TEST');
...expected "[, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, ILIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )"; ... [42001-199]
```

It is marking the string as a problem.

I have also try `insert into users values(2,'test','test')` and `insert into users values('test','test')` unsuccessfully.

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Your error message is not complete, it looks like something was removed from it, I don't see a `"` character after the SQL code. You need to post the whole original error. Most likely you have a problem with `'` characters somewhere, such as stray unexpected `'` character somewhere at the beginning, because H2 doesn't place the error mark `[*]` **inside** string literals.

Comment: Certainly I must be providing something wrong to H2, but the query is shown there...

Comment: “bad SQL grammar” is not a message from H2. Which library or tool are you using in the middle between your application and H2? Maybe there is a some problem in it or in its configuration?

Comment: Mmm.. It is Spring...

Comment: You need to add `spring` and possibly other related tags to your question and include Java code that you use to invoke the query. It doesn't look like a problem with your SQL or with H2.

Comment: However, "[42001-199]" looks like aa H2 error code to me. And the "expected..." too (https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/main/org/h2/command/Parser.java)

Comment: Yes, inner part is from H2, but error message from H2 was truncated and doesn't contain the whole SQL that was finally passed to H2. Your original command is valid for H2, but it looks like it was modified in the middle or wasn't written properly in your Java code. You need to show how exactly you invoke this command.