# Timestamp comparison using MyBatis QueryWrapper

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis, mybatis-plus

I'm trying to make a timestamp comparison after parsing a couple strings that have the default "dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy" in java, using MyBatisPlus for a postgresql DB.

I'm updating legacy code so I'm not able to change a lot of the structure, so that's a constraint since it's using QueryWrapper to execute all queries. I've tried to read the documentation, but I mostly find references in chinese language which don't get translated properly.

What I have tried so far is the following:

```
QueryWrapper<SomeClassWithBaseMapper> result = new QueryWrapper();
        result.eq("firstcolumn", firstValueToCheck);
        if(dateStrFilter != null) {
            try{
                //PostgreSQL Syntax
                 String dateConversionEq = "(TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTRING(" + START_TIMESTAMP +
                  ",5), 'Mon DD HH24:MI:SS xxx YYYY')+(INTERVAL'10 MINUTES')) >= (TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTRING({0},5), " +
                  "'Mon DD HH24:MI:SS xxx YYYY'))";
                result.apply(dateConversionEq, dateStrFilter);

            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
```

I use substring to remove the starting name of the day (since I don't see any matching format pattern in postgresql docs).
I attempt to use `+(INTERVAL'10 MINUTES')` basically to check whether the given date is at most 10 minutes old. But I get this error:

`expected "[, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, ILIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND"`

If I remove this inline interval addition, the query works, but obviously I need results that are recent (in the last 10 minutes). Any suggestion to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: what's `xxx` in `...SS xxx YYYY`?

Comment: and what do you get when you do `System.out.println(dateConversionEq)`?

Comment: I put xxx just as a placeholder to skip the timezone. It seems to work fine. 

The dateConversionEq value is:
WHERE firstcolumn = ? AND (TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTRING(start_timestamp,5), 'Mon DD HH24:MI:SS xxx YYYY')) >= (TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTRING(?,5), 'Mon DD HH24:MI:SS xxx YYYY')) 

An actual date string example is: "Wed Sep 14 10:38:07 CDT 2022"

Comment: Seems to be an issue with Java or MyBatis? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60861099/h2-failing-to-insert-data